# Basic Gradle copy-task not working (until directly called)

Tags: gradle, copy, mkdir

I have a simple Gradle script:

```
task copyall(){
    println 'starting...'
    task copyA(type: Copy) {
        mkdir 'web'
        from 'src'
        into 'web'
    }
}
```

It behaves strangely: if I call "gradle copyall" from command line - it creates directory but doesn't copy files from 'src' to 'web' folders.
If I call directly task.copyA ("gradle copyA") from command line - it does both makes dir and copying files (with subfolders).

Why task.copyA is only partially executed as subtask of task.copyall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I understand why your Gradle script behaves the way you describe, but it behaves this way for various reasons.

First of all, there is no such thing as a subtask in Gradle. You can create tasks and you can define dependencies between tasks, that's it. So your task `copyA` is exactly the same thing if you just define it on its own (the recommended way):

```
task copyAll {
    println 'starting...'
}

task copyA(type: Copy) {
    mkdir 'web'
    from 'src'
    into 'web'
}
```

Now you have two tasks, but the task `copyAll` does nothing at all. Even your `println` statement is not, what the task does, but how it is configured:

Gradle has two major phases when executing build scripts: **configuration phase** and **execution phase**. The whole build script will be evaluated (executed) during configuration phase and only the task actions (e.g. copying for a `Copy` task), `doFirst` and `doLast` closures of selected tasks will be executed during execution phase. The selected tasks are determined from the command line parameters and task dependencies.

As a conclusion, the `'starting ...'` output is printed when task `copyAll` is configured, not when it is started!

Last but not least, the `mkdir` command is causing confusion, because it is not part of the [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task, but a [method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#mkdir-java.lang.Object-) of the `Project` instance. It executed directly when called, so in your case directly during the configuration phase, completely independent from any task execution. It will be executed every time you execute Gradle.

But, to hear some good news, you simply don't need it. A `Copy` task will create all required target directories on its own.

Now, to summarize all points from above, we come up with the following build script:

```
task copyAll {
    dependsOn 'copyA'
}

task copyA(type: Copy) {
    from 'src'
    into 'web'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I took for granted that subtasking is natural, guess I'd expected some kind of error if it were not. 'Starting...' output and mkdir execution without executing task were also puzzling before your explanation - thought I saw "Build successful" without any task executed, I couldn't explain it either.

Comment: The most counter-intuitive mechanism in Gradle is the task closure being for configuration only. Everyone expects the closure to be executed when the task is executed, but in fact it will be executed right when the task is created. Also, if you don't know for sure what (and when) a method does, always check back where it comes from. There are a lot of methods in the `Project` object that are executed directly, some of them even copy a specific task behaviour and configuration interface (`delete`, `copy`, `exec`...).